# In generics, is it possible to add 1 if integer or 0.1 if float?

Tags: generics, rust, binary-search

I have this generics where `Num` is defined in [`num` crate](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/index.html):

```rust
//finds `x` where `f(x) == Equal` for `x ∈ [left, right)`
fn binary_search<T: Debug + Copy + PartialOrd + Num, F: FnMut(T) -> Ordering>(
    mut left: T,
    mut right: T, //exclusive
    mut f: F,
) -> Result<T, T> {
    while (left < right) {
        let mid = left + (right - left) / (T::one() + T::one());
        match f(mid) {
            Less => left = mid + T::one(),
            Greater => right = mid,
            Equal => return Ok(mid),
        }
    }
    Err(left)
}
```

This binary search works correctly for integer types but NOT for float types (like `f64`). The evil part is this:

```rust
Less => left = mid + T::one(),
```

The `T::one()` should instead be `1e-6` for float and `1` for integer. Is it possible?

Here's the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=92bd28e40bb0c2e904527ad5584a451a) with some automated tests available. I want to make `binary_search_02()` pass without breaking `binary_search_01()`.

Comment: How about making `left` exclusive as well?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Seems a very good idea. Should I then treat `left = 0usize` specially (e.g. `if (left == T::one()) { ... }` right before `while`), I think?

Answer (score 3):

The `Less` and `Greater` arms aren't symmetrical, which is why you have to adjust the midpoint in one but not the other. You can fix it by making both endpoints inclusive. Then there's no need to nudge the midpoint.

```
pub fn binary_search<
    T: Debug + Copy + PartialOrd + Num,
    F: FnMut(T) -> Ordering,
>(
    mut left: T,  // inclusive
    mut right: T, // inclusive
    mut f: F,
) -> Result<T, T> {
    loop {
        let mid = left + (right - left) / (T::one() + T::one());
        match f(mid) {
            Less => {
                if left == mid {
                    break;
                }
                left = mid;
            }
            Greater => {
                if right == mid {
                    break;
                }
                right = mid;
            }
            Equal => return Ok(mid),
        }
    }
    Err(right)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f7eecd485e5f9d408bf4af7a38642549)

Note that I changed the final return value to `Err(right)` to get the tests to pass. I'm not sure if that's correct? You can play with it if it isn't.

Comment: Thank you. Is `right` really inclusive? `let l = vec![0, 3, 5, 20]; assert_eq!(Err(4), binary_search(0, l.len(), |i| l[i].cmp(&100)));` passes though `Err(3)` is returned when `l.len() - 1` instead of `l.len()` is used. Also, the tests in your playground passed even when replacing `l.len() - 1` to `l.len()`. (Sorry I should have mentioned in advance, but the binary search in OP is almost from the standard `slice::binary_search_by()`, so the meaning of `Err` is same as that.) Anyway, I'll re-read your implementation and play with it :)

Comment: Yeah, I think the `Err(right)` at the end is wrong or insufficient. Figuring out what to return when the search value is greater than the last element is tricky. Perhaps the function should return `Result<T, Option<T>>` where `Err(None)` indicates that the insertion point is after the last element.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own trait and implement it for integer and floating-point types:

```
trait Delta {
    fn delta() -> Self;
}

impl Delta for i32 {
    fn delta() -> Self { 1 }
}

impl Delta for f32 {
    fn delta() -> Self { 1e-6 }
}

fn main() {
    println!("i32: {}", i32::delta());
    println!("f32: {}", f32::delta());
}
```

If you don't want to manually implement `Delta` for all types, you can do it with a macro:

```
macro_rules! impl_delta {
    ($v:expr, $($t:ty),*) => {
        $(
        impl Delta for $t {
            fn delta() -> Self { $v }
        }
        )*
    }
}

impl_delta!(1, i8, i16, i32, i64);
impl_delta!(1e-6, f32, f64);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec3b8ff89ff32c545b5e19145259e738)

Comment: I like this solution and it seems this is like how `T::one()` is implemented ([source](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.14/src/num_traits/identities.rs.html#120)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`num::FromPrimitive` trait](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.FromPrimitive.html) where some conversion methods are defined:

```rust
pub trait FromPrimitive {
    pub fn from_i64(n: i64) -> Option<Self>;
    pub fn from_u64(n: u64) -> Option<Self>;
    /* snip */
    pub fn from_f32(n: f32) -> Option<Self> { ... }
    pub fn from_f64(n: f64) -> Option<Self> { ... }
}
```

So define `delta` as

```rust
let delta = {
    let delta = T::from_f64(1e-9).unwrap();
    if (delta == T::zero()) { //if integer types
        T::one()
    } else { //if float types
        delta
    }
};
```

and add it instead of `T::one()`

```rust
Less => left = mid + delta,
```

The final code is this, making all the tests pass:

```rust
fn binary_search<
    T: fmt::Debug + Copy + cmp::PartialOrd + Num + FromPrimitive,
    F: FnMut(T) -> Ordering,
>(
    mut left: T,
    mut right: T, //exclusive
    mut f: F,
) -> Result<T, T> {
    let delta = {
        let delta = T::from_f64(1e-9).unwrap();
        if (delta == T::zero()) {
            T::one()
        } else {
            delta
        }
    };
    while (left < right) {
        let mid = left + (right - left) / (T::one() + T::one());
        match f(mid) {
            Less => left = mid + delta,
            Greater => right = mid,
            Equal => return Ok(mid),
        }
    }
    Err(left)
}
```

Comment: There's a [`next_up`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.next_up) method. Almost perfect except it's still experimental.